# How can I make a pigglet headed LEGO figure to be a sidekick for my Gadget Hero?

Tags: building, minifigures, customization

I have a LEGO superhero that I painted, and he needs a sidekick. The Sidekick is a boy who has the head of a pigglet! But how do I make a Pigglet head?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the head piece from a [Gamorrean Guard](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Gamorrean_Guard).  This piece can be found in the following sets:

> 4476 Jabba's Prize
>
> 6210 Jabba's Sail Barge
>
> 9516 Jabba's Palace

Answer (score 10):

The 1979–1989 Fabuland animals figures have a human body slightly larger than a minifigure, the head, arms and legs move but cannot be removed. The figures are no longer produced but remain quite popular amongst AFOL's. They can still be purchased on sites like [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=fab11a&in=S).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's a *bit* late, but in 2020 the Monkie Kid line contains a [minifigure-sized pig head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=67887pb01&idColor=104#T=C&C=104):

[image: Pigsy head]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is one of the pig minifigures from the now-discontinued 2016 [The Angry Birds Movie](https://brickipedia.fandom.com/wiki/The_Angry_Birds_Movie) theme. For example, see set 75822, Piggy Plane Attack:

[image: LEGO 75822, Piggy Plane Attack]